# Unable to locate package libopenssl1.8

Tags: openssl

In response to this post http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/188432, I am trying to install libopenssl1.8, but I get an error:

viggy@ubuntu:~/Documents/github/Core3$ sudo apt-get install libopenssl1.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libopenssl1.8
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libopenssl1.8'

Answer (score 1):

The package you are looking for is called libopenssl-ruby1.8, which has been discontinued with the current version of Ubuntu in favor of libruby1.8, which includes the desired package along with several others.

Comment: libruby1.8 is the general libraries for Ruby. The OP is looking specifically for openssl libraries. If libruby1.8 has said libraries, you might want to make that clear (such as documentation that says such).

Comment: Unfortunately, while libruby1.8 did install fine, the initial error still occurs " no such file to load -- openssl (RuntimeError)"

Comment: I don't think that is an ubuntu problem, so this is not the right place to ask for help.  The ruby forum or stack overflow might be good places to start.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=libopenssl) packages.ubuntu.com page, the package is now `libruby1.8`.